# I cannot move CircularImageView in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, circleimage

I've been struggling for days trying to move the CircularImageView to the right of the toolbar without success.

I would like to have it to the right and more centered (i.e. without touching toolbar edges), but I cannot do it.
Just for info, I tried to use both mikhaellopez and hdodenhof libraries without success.

Here what I tried (with a placeholder image in the CircularImageView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/page_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_seed_48dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

```
public class HomepageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage_activity);
        pageToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(pageToolbar);
        ...
}
```

[image: This is the result]

Another question: is it possible to have CircularImageView with a plain background (e.g. white)? In fact it is not shown unless I put something within it and I had to put a placeholder image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use only a plain background, don't about the library you're using but with hdodenof's you can try this:

```
app:civ_fill_color="@android:color/white"
```

Also try adding this to your `CircularImageView`

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

The `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` is as a backup support for RTL layouts, used while creating apps which render layout from RTL instead of LTR.

Comment: Awesome, now it works, thank you! Just a question: the CircularImageView disappears if I don't put something into it. Is there a way to have it with a simple white background?

Comment: yes there is: try this if you are using hdodenhof's library: `app:civ_fill_color="@android:color/white" ` 
I'm glad it worked for you. pls mark it as an answer so other's will also benefit from it.